# Just bought a Nicol bike and not sure who makes them

Tags: road

I just bought a road bike and the only logo on it is Nicol, does anyone have a clue who made this bike and what it’s worth?

Thanks[image]

Comment: Sorry but item valuations are off-topic, here. Your bike says "Nicol" on the down-tube and seems to have some words on the top-tube (or is that just scratched paint that looks like writing at this resolution?). Isn't one of those likely to be the answer to who made the bike?

Comment: If you just bought it, you are probably the one who has latest valuation.

Answer (score 4):

the person who founded ibis bicycles is named Scott Nicol.  Ibis is known for mountain bikes so maybe it is an early pre Ibis by Scott Nicol or maybe not.

more pictures might help

The braze at the seat post looks like a hand braze, but its hard to tell from the picture.  It might be a hand built frame.

I would send an email to ibis and ask. Their web site says they have around 20 employees. It might be worth something to them.